# Whow to convert mp4 file in Wav audio file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wav, mp4

I would like to convert an.mp4 file (with audio only [e.g.](https://v.redd.it/b2wdjyw818i31/audio?source=fallback)) download from the reddit API to assemble it with its [corresponding video](https://v.redd.it/b2wdjyw818i31/DASH_480?source=fallback) (without sound).

Is there any way to do this under node.js?

Comment: Take a look at FFmpeg.  And yes, you can execute FFmpeg as a child process under your Node.js application.

Comment: I gonna take a look at it tomorrow, thx

Comment: Ffmpeg look at doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge .mp4 audio and video files with [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg), an *ffmpeg* commands layer for *Node.js* that avoid you launching it as a child process.

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg()
  .input('audio.mp4', 'video.mp4')
  .output('out.mp4')
  .run();
```

And if you want to convert the audio output to wav audio, just specify the .wav extension and *ffmpeg* will convert it for you.

```
.output('out.wav')
```